# Forming peaceful teams

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, puzzle

Let us have set of $n=mk$ people that have to be divided into $m$ teams, each with $k$ members. Let us denote the set of the people $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and the teams $S_i\subset S$. We consider a function $L:S\times S\to[0,1]$ where for $s,s'\in S$, $L(s,s')$ expresses for arguments how much $s$ likes $s'$. Generally $L(s,s')\neq L(s',s)$.

**Task**: how to form the teams so the minimal love, that is defined for given teams as
$$
\min_{i=1\dots m}\left(\min_{s,s'\in S_i}L(s,s')\right),
$$
 is maximal?

Comment: so outside it should be a maximum, or not?

Comment: Yes, there shall be practically $\arg\max_{\rm formations}\min_{i}\left(\min_{s_1,s_2} \dots\right)$ but I rather used the plain language in order not to overformalize it.

Comment: no, the min over $i$ should be a max over $i$.

Comment: It's a bit confusing that you uses $S_1,...,S_n$ to denote people and then $S_i\subset S$ to denote teams. That being said, your problem looks very much like minimum cuts in directed graphs.

Comment: There is $\min$ over $i$. Each team has a most problematic relationship, given by $\min$ over $s_1,s_2$. The second $\min$ determines the most problematic relationship among all teams. The teams have to be formed so this relationship as good as possible.

Comment: whast have you tried?

Comment: To order the relationships from lowest (hate) to highest (love). Then taking the relationships of lowest values (hate) and putting them in different teams so I assure that they will not be together.

Comment: The notation is far to be clear. It seems a copy-paste from somewhere.

Comment: @Masacroso What is not clear to you?

Comment: All @KarelMacek. It is very confusing denote $n$ and at the same time $S$. It will be more clear denote $n=|S|$ or something like this. Anyway I think I understood but, in the first read it wasnt so clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you relax your problem such that $L(s,s')=L(s',s)$, then it's much like undirected graph cut:

Let $\begin{pmatrix}W_{ij}\end{pmatrix}=L(s_i,s_j)$, so that $e_{n,i}^\top W e_{n,j}=L(s_i,s_j)$. Notice $e_{n,i}$ here denotes the $i$th canonical $n$-dimensional vector, for example $e_{4,2}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^\top$.
If the vector $e_{n,i}$ denotes $s_i$, then a team $S_a\subset S$ is
$$
f_a=\sum_{i\in S_a} e_{n,i}\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Notice that $f_i^\top W f_i$ is the amount of love within team $S_i$ and $f_i^\top W f_j$ is the amount of love between teams $S_i$ and $S_j$.

Now, your problem becomes this one :
$$
\min_{f_1,\dots,f_k} f^\top W f : f_i\text{ more or less defined as in \eqref{1}}, f\perp \mathbb 1,\|f\|=\sqrt{n}
$$

You can check [Luxburg 2007](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Luxburg07_tutorial_4488%5B0%5D.pdf) for more details about why the problem is like that and how to solve it.

However, know that this problem is NP-hard. You should not expect to find the optimal solution.